# How to start mainactivity in a BroadcasrReceiver class?

Tags: java, android

How can I start `Main_Activity` from a `BroadcastReceiver` class?
I made a search and I found this code but I don't know where to put my package name.

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();
 intent.setClassName("com.package.my", "com.package.my.abc");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

My package name is `com.example.tes`.

Log:

```
01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326): Process: com.example.tes, PID: 1326

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.tes.SMSReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2426)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1034)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1021)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:311)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:311)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at com.example.tes.SMSReceiver.onReceive(SMSReceiver.java:47)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2419)

01-15 08:49:23.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

why not starting it using app context:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
  context.startActivity (intent);
```

Comment: please provide the full code of the onReceive method so I can help you

Comment: usually you must add the code inside your question by editing it, I edited it with the code you posted in the comment. 


where is the part when you want to navigate to MainActivity

Comment: str += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
    Text += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
    str += "\n";
    
    if (Text != ""){
     
     
     
     
     
      Intent myInt = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
       context.startActivity (myInt);
     
   
    }
     }

Comment: got it, you missed the variable name, it's  `myInt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` **NOT** `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68972/discussion-on-answer-by-muhammed-refaat-how-to-start-mainactivity-in-a-broadcasr).